Do one-way functions imply target collision resistance?
I'm reading the paper:
One-Way Functions are Necessary and Sufficient for Secure Signatures, by John Rompel,
which gives answer to the question in the title; but I'm confused about these sketched proofs (like lemma2, lemma4 and lemma5 ).
The author said there exists the full version of this paper, while I can't find it in Google. What's worse, I can't find his email address. It seems that he hasn't published any papers since 1994. Can anybody provide me the full proof?

I've changed the question so that it is asking for a direct proof rather than a question about finding a person or document as that is considered off topic. A quick search shows a weird reference from 1994: in "Randomness-Efficient Oblivious Sampling
Mihir Bellare∗ John Rompel†" the † reads: "Work done while the author was at MIT. Present whereabouts unknown." I think he was a graduate student there (a subsequent search corroborates this narative) and moved on.

It's very common in CS not to end up publishing full papers, especially if the student moved on and work was superseded by others. One suggestion I have is to search for the author's name in Thesis databases--typically full proofs are supplied in Theses.
